# MFC: sending a msg from worker thread to the Main thread to stop the worker thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

I am fixing a GUI application programmed with MFC. To run a communication stack a new thread is created. On some events I want to stop this but I know that only in the worker thread and I cannot get the correct behaviour from stopping the worker thread from itself. So I need to send a message to the main thread and tell it to stop the worker thread so that the main thread can then take the correct action.

I am unsure how to do this. I have looked at the SendMessage function in CWnd but it does not take threadid as an argument and I dont get what I need to include to use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: 'I cannot get the correct behaviour from stopping the worker thread from itself' - why?  I suspect that data that should belong in the thread is not - you got comms components plonked onto the form, by any chance, or is it the other way round - the GUI directly accesses data in the thread class?

Comment: Well if there is a reset command coming into the comm stack the stack should stop and start itself. problem is if I call the Stop function then the thread is terinated and then it obv cannot call the start function since it no longer exists.

Comment: OK, don't stop the thread.  Put a while(true){try...catch} round the entire comms init/setup/run code in the thread and, if you detect an error, throw.

Comment: If you use `SendMessage`/`PostMessage` with a custom message (`WM_APP + x`) you can pass anything you like as the `WPARAM` and `LPARAM`. The system will not interpret the message for you in any way but will simply pass the parameters you provide to your message handler.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the only safe way to do anything to a worker thread is from within the worker thread itself. It should probably be structured as a while(bRun) loop so it runs until the program is shutting down. Whatever you are trying to do (stop and start) should be handled by code in the while loop.